# Регулярные выражения Python из ссылки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из текста ссылки `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHJUUmmmnU8&ab_channel=ADV-IT`

выразить zHJUUmmmnU8

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

re_url = re.compile(r'v=(\w+)')
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHJUUmmmnU8&ab_channel=ADV-IT'
print(re_url.findall(url)) #['zHJUUmmmnU8']
```